# Criminals commit a crime and people commit suicide. Why can’t we omit the article ‘a’ before crime and include ‘a’ before suicide?

Tags: grammar, articles, nouns, spoken-english, uncountable-nouns

Why can’t we say criminals commit crime and people commit a suicide?

Comment: But you can do that … (Even if *commit **a** suicide* sounds a bit odd, it's still syntactically possible. And *commit crime* is used all the time)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside suicide for the moment, when it comes to committing crimes you may hear either:

- he committed murder
- he committed *a* murder
- he committed *an act* of murder

I'm sure you know that the use of articles can make something unique, or countable. When it comes to crimes, they are counted in different ways depending on the context. For example, if someone kills two people at the same time, they have committed *an act* of murder, but *two counts* of murder.

It also depends very much on whether the language used is legal language (eg in a courtroom) or everyday speech. In the field of law you might hear "two counts of murder", or a "double murder", but in everyday speech many people would say "committed two murders" or more likely "they murdered two people".

---

When it comes to suicide, I should point out that in recent times there has been much effort to replace the expression "committed suicide" with "took his/her life" or similar, as it is felt the language could be hurtful or insensitive to those affected by it. However, the logical reason why "committed suicide" would never have an article is because it could never be counted - no person can commit any suicide but their own, so an article would be redundant.